# Spring Cloud support of leadership election

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-cloud

I have a Tomcat web app running on AWS. I would like to have several instances of it instead of only one, mainly to avoid down-time in case of problems on one instance. I need a concept of a "leader instance" because some operations should not be carried out by all instances but only one of them. Does Spring Cloud support leadership election and quorum out of the box?
P.S. I would like to avoid the obvious ZooKeeper, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some preliminary work going on in [spring-cloud-cluster](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-cluster).  It is not released (or supported) yet.  You have your choice of implementation, currently: zookeeper, redis or hazelcast.  Other implementations shouldn't be hard to do either.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look into those. How about [etcd](https://github.com/coreos/etcd)?

Comment: There's nothing stopping anyone from implementing an `etcd` implementation.  Pull requests welcome.